# Why is my sprite moving 90 degrees to the right?

Tags: javascript, rotation, trigonometry

I have a sprite which i'm trying to move towards the top of the screen with the left and right buttons adjusting the heading.

However when my `heading = 0;` my sprite moves off to the right.

Here's what im using to adjust my heading:

```
function calcHeading() {
        if (heading>360 ) {
            heading = 0;
        } else if (rightPressed) {
            heading++
        } else if (leftPressed) {
            heading--
        }

        if (heading<0) {
            heading = 359;
        }
}
```

Heres what im using to adjust my x and y positions:

```
    function adjustBoatPos() {
    boatDX = Math.cos(heading * (Math.PI / 180));
    boatDY = Math.sin(heading * (Math.PI / 180));

    boatPosX = boatPosX + boatDX;
    boatPosY = boatPosY + boatDY;
}
```

I can fix this by rotating my sprite in the function that draws it like this:

```
function drawBoat() {
    drawImageRot(boat, boatPosX-(boatWidth/2), boatPosY-(boatHeight/2), boatWidth, boatHeight, heading+90);
}
```

however this "solution" makes the heading variable incorrect(when moving up it is 270)

How can i make my sprite move towards the top of the screen when the `heading = 0`?

I'm using pure JavaScript and a `<canvas>` element.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("game-window"); //store a reference to the canvas element
 var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'); // create a variable to store the 2d rendering context
 var canvasWidth = 256; //set the canvas width...
 var canvasHeight = 256; //... and height

 var boat = new Image(); //create new image element for boat
 var boatWidth = 16; //define the sprites width...
 var boatHeight = 16; //... and height
 boat.src = 'https://github.com/Synj24/expert-potato/blob/master/crappy-placeholder.png?raw=true'; //set souce of boat image

 var map =  new Image(); //create a new image element for the map
 var mapWidth = 768; //define the maps width...
 var mapHeight = 768; //... and height
 map.src = 'https://github.com/Synj24/expert-potato/blob/master/crappy-placeholder-map.png?raw=true' //set source of the map image

 var rightPressed = false;
 var leftPressed = false;

 var heading = 0;
 var vHeading = 0.01;

 var boatPosX = canvasWidth/2;
 var boatPosY = canvasHeight/2;
 var boatDX = 0;
 var boatDY = 0;

 document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
 document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);

 function keyDownHandler(e) {
     if(e.keyCode == 39) {
         rightPressed = true;
     }
     else if(e.keyCode == 37) {
         leftPressed = true;
     }
 }
 function keyUpHandler(e) {
     if(e.keyCode == 39) {
         rightPressed = false;
     }
     else if(e.keyCode == 37) {
         leftPressed = false;
     }
 }

 function adjustBoatPos() {
  boatDX = Math.cos(heading * (Math.PI / 180));
  boatDY = Math.sin(heading * (Math.PI / 180));

  boatPosX = boatPosX + boatDX;
  boatPosY = boatPosY + boatDY;
 }

 function calcHeading() {
   if (heading>360 ) {
    heading = 0;
   } else if (rightPressed) {
    heading++
   } else if (leftPressed) {
    heading--
   }

   if (heading<0) {
    heading = 359;
   }
 }

 function debugText(x,y) {
  ctx.fillStyle = "grey";
  ctx.fillRect(x, y+17, 80, 100);
  ctx.font = "bold 16px Arial";
  ctx.fillStyle = "#FB5167";
  ctx.fillText("  X:"+Math.round(boatPosX * 100) / 100, x+2, (y+25) +8);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#FBE551";
  ctx.fillText("  Y:"+Math.round(boatPosY * 100) / 100, x+2, (y+25) +24);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#FB9051";
  ctx.fillText("dX:"+Math.round(boatDX * 100) / 100, x+2, (y+25) +40);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#FB51BC";
  ctx.fillText("dY:"+Math.round(boatDY * 100) / 100, x+2, (y+25) +56);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#BCFB51";
  ctx.fillText("  H:"+heading, x+2, (y+25) +72);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#9051FB";
  ctx.fillText("vH:"+vHeading, x+2, (y+25) +88);
 }

 function drawImageRot(img,x,y,width,height,deg){
     var rad = deg * Math.PI / 180; //Convert degrees to radian
     ctx.translate(x + width / 2, y + height / 2); //Set the origin to the center of the image
     ctx.rotate(rad); //Rotate the canvas around the origin
     ctx.drawImage(img,width / 2 * (-1),height / 2 * (-1),width,height); //draw the image  
     ctx.rotate(rad * ( -1 ) );
     ctx.translate((x + width / 2) * (-1), (y + height / 2) * (-1)); //reset the canvas  
 }

 function drawBoat() {
  drawImageRot(boat, boatPosX-(boatWidth/2), boatPosY-(boatHeight/2), boatWidth, boatHeight, heading);
 }

 function drawMap() {
  ctx.drawImage(map, (mapWidth/3-canvasWidth*2), (mapHeight/3-canvasHeight*2));//draw the map
 }

 function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0 ,0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight); //clear the canvas
  drawMap();
  calcHeading();
  adjustBoatPos();
  drawBoat();
  debugText(0, canvasHeight/2);
 }
 setInterval(draw, 10);
```

```html
<canvas id="game-window" width="256px" height="256px"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your boat goes left when heading is `0` because *cos( 0 )* is `1` which is the delta you give to your `boatPosX`.

Since your boat image is draw pointing upwards this makes it point the wrong way as a zero rotation for the image is **up**, whilst a zero heading for the velocity is **right**.

You can either re-draw the image so that it points right or subtract `90` from the `heading` before doing the `cos` and `sin` operations;

```
boatDX = Math.cos((heading - 90) * (Math.PI / 180));
boatDY = Math.sin((heading - 90) * (Math.PI / 180));
```

You can [try the last solution](https://jsfiddle.net/rr922zdu/) at JSFiddle.